# How to post data in part of a form using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a form like this:

```
<form id="abc">

<div id="xyz" >
//some elements
</div>
</form>
```

I have bound the submit event like this:

```
$(function(){
 $('#abc').submit(function(event){
    //I want to post the data (form fields stored in element 'xyz')
    $.post(/**/);
});
});
```

How may I post only the elements in div 'xyz' ?

**[Edit]**

When I use $(#id).serialize(), I am getting the (url encoded) key value pair. I merely want the value. the data I am trying to extract is in a textarea. It consists of a set of emails, separated by a comma. I want to post the emails to the server. I can either post the data as a JSON array (which means I will have to parse the string clientside), or send the string to the server - which is better practise?

Comment: you will have to send the key/value. Server side you will need to request based on the key ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just serialize the div:

```
$myData=$('#xyz').serialize();
```

Comment: true that, I usually have to use classes rather than ids, so I'll fix it for this scenario:)